# Mongoose, $pull an element from nested array and update document based on the presence of the element

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on a mongoose schema similar to this:

```
const actionSchema = {
    actions: {
        type: [{
            actionName: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            count: {
                type: Number,
                default: 0,
                required: true
            },
            users: [{
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'User'
            }]
        }]
    }};
```

It is a nested schema of a post schema.
Here, actions are dynamically generated and number of people does that action are maintained by count and their identity is maintained by users array.

As you see, actions is an array of objects which further contain users array.
I want to check if a provided user id is present in any of the action object and then remove it from array and also reduce the count.

Being totally new to mongoose and mongodb, one simple way I see is to find the post using `Post.findById()` which has to be updated, run js loops, update the post and call `.save()`. But it can be very costly when users array has thousands of user ids.
I tried `.update()` but can't understand how to use it in this case.

How about adding a method to the Post Model (like `postSchema.methods.removeUserAction`)? This gives access to document from `this` and allows to update the document and thus call `.save()`. Does it loads the full document to the client node application?

So please suggest the right way.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simplify your model, for example

```
// Model - Actions Model

const actionSchema = {
   actionName: {
       type: String,
       required: true
   },
   user: {
       type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
       ref: 'User'
   }
};
```

And you can easily get the total actions via `Model.count()`, get specific action count with `Model.count({ actionName: 'action name'})`, and removing entries with `Model.delete(condition)`. Unless there's a reason why you have it modeled this way.

Comment: I can surely remove the "count", but still, since actionSchema is nested schema of post model, I would rather nest this new actionSchema as an array. ex: `actions: [actionSchema]`

Comment: Well, as long as you are sure that the document will not grow beyond the allowed MongoDB document size limit. All you'll need is to do a $push or $pull to add or remove entries in actions array.

Comment: @NeetigyaChahar Kindly upvote and accept the answer if it works for you. It will help your reputation as well. :)

Comment: I still have a doubt. I have created this schema. But to get count of users for every action, I need to use `.aggregate()` with `{$group: {...}`. Also to load each post I need to make two queries. One for actions and their count and another one to load other details. As this is for a social media site, each post maybe loaded multiple times within few seconds. So I guess it greatly increases the cost on database. That's why I wanted to have `count` field so as to load the post details with action counts at one go.  I will update count when action is made. I just need your suggestions on this.

Comment: This schema finally helped me. Thanks.